# Insert data into table from another table based on non matching column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have two tables. Staging table refreshes every day and replaces `LoadDate` column with today's date. This data gets inserted into Final table where I want to insert just the new data.

Staging table:

| MachineName | ApplicationName | LoadDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Excel | 22-02-2023 |
| B | Excel | 22-02-2023 |
| C | PowerPoint | 22-02-2023 |
| D | Word | 22-02-2023 |
| A | Word | 22-02-2023 |
| C | Word | 22-02-2023 |

Final table:

| MachineName | ApplicationName | LoadDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Excel | 20-02-2023 |
| B | Excel | 20-02-2023 |
| C | PowerPoint | 21-02-2023 |
| A | Word | 21-02-2023 |

I have written my query like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Final]
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Staging]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [FINAL]
                      WHERE [Final].[MachineName] = [Staging].[MachineName]
                        AND [Final].[ApplicationName] = [Staging].[ApplicationName])
```

E.g in the Final table, A-Excel, B-Excel, C-PowerPoint and A-Word were already present in the table so they stay as they are. In the Staging table C-Word and D-Word is the new value and this needs to get inserted into the Final table. Although I have written the query to the best of my knowledge, I am getting duplicate values in the Final table which should not happen. What have I done wrong?

Comment: sounds like you might want to read up on MERGE, specifically WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target

Comment: I think you want upsert functionality here, i.e. insert and/or update.

Comment: @RickyTillson I had tried that previously but unfortunately, I couldn't do it. It was doing reverse of what I wanted. It was updating old rows with new data. Will try to solve using it again.

Comment: @DhirajD sound like you were using WHEN MATCHED and updating. With a MERGE you've got 3 different outcomes and a typical use for each; WHEN MATCHED = update what you've already got, WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target = insert new data, WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source = delete something no longer in staging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work as you expect it to. Are you certain that you supplied the SQL that is causing duplication?

As an alternative, here is a MERGE statement:

```sql
MERGE Final AS tgt
USING Staging AS src
ON tgt.MachineName=src.MachineName
AND tgt.ApplicationName=src.ApplicationName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT(MachineName, ApplicationName, LoadDate)
VALUES(MachineName,ApplicationName,LoadDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for the help. I used this query and it is working properly now.

```
MERGE INTO [Final]
USING [Staging]
on [Final].[MachineName]=[Staging].[MachineName]
AND [Final].[ApplicationName]=[Staging].[ApplicationName]
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT(
              [MachineName]       
              ,[ApplicationName]
              ,[Load Date]        
        )
VALUES(
[Staging].[MachineName] 
,[Staging].[ApplicationName]
,[Staging].[Load Date]
);
```